# Macxchange Script to Change MAC and Hostname in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: perl, bash, shell, scripting, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to adapt a script in backtrack to work with Ubuntu. I keep getting an error on line 14 which is the `if [ $? == 0 ]; then` line.

The script was found on http://pctechtips.org/script-to-change-mac-and-hostname-in-backtrack/

The code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#author: Jorge L. Vazquez
#purpose: this script will change the mac address to random
#and will pick a random word from password.lst in jtr for hostname
#change variables "interface" and "file" to your settings
#also macchanger needs to be installed

INTERFACE=eth0
FILE=/pentest/passwords/jtr/password.lst
WORD=$(sort -R $FILE | head -1)

#changing mac address to random
ifconfig $INTERFACE down > /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    printf "%s\nChanging mac address...\n"
    macchanger -r $INTERFACE
else
    printf "%sScript encounter an error, sorry...\n"
    exit 1
fi

#changing hostname to random word from password.lst
printf "%s\nChanging Hostname...\n"
OLDHOST=$(hostname)
hostname $WORD
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    printf "%sPrevius Hostname: $OLDHOST \n"
    printf "%sRandom Hostname: $WORD \n"
else
    printf "%sScript encounter an error, sorry...\n"
    exit 1
fi

#putting interface up
ifconfig $INTERFACE up > /dev/null
printf "\n"


#END
```

And the wordlist file for the hostfile (password.lst) looks like this

```
# A couple of merged /etc/hosts files -- 
#
4000ex
a-lhi-bbn-01
a-lhi-sri-03
a00
a1
a2
```

I run the script using `sh filename.sh` and I've given it executable access and macchanger is installed but I still get an error which is `14: [: 0: unexpected operator
Script encounter an error, sorry...`

Comment: You haven't told us what the error message is...

Comment: @Jim Garrison Woops I'll add it 14: [: 0: unexpected operator
Script encounter an error, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
```

instead.  The `==` is not the canonical way to write it in bash, but most versions accept it.

Don't forget to repeat the fix at the second occurrence below.

Comment: Thanks Alfe it changes the Hardware Address in the terminal window (I checked using ifconfig) but it doesn't change in the ubuntu networking gui..Any ideas why?

Comment: I guess the networking GUI might just cache that value.  You could try reloading this.  Maybe `sudo restart network-manager` does the trick.

Comment: what ever changes I make with ifconfig seems to get over written by ubuntu's network-manager process.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason this script isn't part of the standard Ubuntu distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You can roll the exit-code checking into the if-statement itself:

```
#changing mac address to random
if ifconfig $INTERFACE down > /dev/null; then
    printf "%s\nChanging mac address...\n"
    macchanger -r $INTERFACE
else
    printf "%sScript encounter an error, sorry...\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

Also note that `==` is [the bash operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for string comparison.  The exit code is an integer, so the correct way to check its value is with `-eq`, which tells bash to interpret the operands as integers:

```
#changing mac address to random
ifconfig $INTERFACE down > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "%s\nChanging mac address...\n"
    macchanger -r $INTERFACE
else
    printf "%sScript encounter an error, sorry...\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

Though since there is no danger of a program having an exit value like "00" instead of "0", using `==` will work as you'd expect in this case.